# Size limit of JSON data type in PostgreSQL

Tags: json, postgresql, postgresql-9.2

Does anyone know what is the limit on the size of JSON data type in PostgreSQL 9.2?

Answer (score 107, accepted):

Looking at the source for PostgreSQL 9.2.1:

```
Source: postgresql-9.2.1\src\backend\utils\adt\json.c:
/*
 * Input.
 */
Datum
json_in(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS)
{
    char       *text = PG_GETARG_CSTRING(0);

    json_validate_cstring(text);

    /* Internal representation is the same as text, for now */
    PG_RETURN_TEXT_P(cstring_to_text(text));
}
```

Update for PostgreSQL 9.3.5:

The code has changed in the `json_in` function, but the json internal representation is still text:

```
Source: postgresql-9.3.5\src\backend\utils\adt\json.c:
/*
 * Input.
 */
Datum
json_in(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS)
{
    char       *json = PG_GETARG_CSTRING(0);
    text       *result = cstring_to_text(json);
    JsonLexContext *lex;

    /* validate it */
    lex = makeJsonLexContext(result, false);
    pg_parse_json(lex, &nullSemAction);

    /* Internal representation is the same as text, for now */
    PG_RETURN_TEXT_P(result);
}
```

So it appears that, for now at least, `json` is the same as a `text` datatype but with JSON validation. The `text` datatype's maximum size is [1GB](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-character.html).

Comment: Does the (new since post?) Postgres `jsonb` data-type use something other than pure text?

Comment: 1GB! that is pretty nice. Glad that number isn't in MB.

Comment: @edencorbin it is 1024 MB :)

Comment: isn't it 1000 mb? ;)

Comment: Technically a MB (MegaByte) is 1000 and a MiB (MebiByte) is 1024 but everyone uses MB (MegaByte) to refer to 1024

Comment: jsonb looks like it's also backed by text (i'm not sure). here is a link to the file: https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/src/backend/utils/adt/json.c and to jsonb file: https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/src/backend/utils/adt/jsonb.c

Comment: @localhostdotdev: if you try to create a large `jsonb` value you can easily hit the error message: "*total size of jsonb object elements exceeds the maximum of 268435455 bytes*" which means that `jsonb` indeed has a limit fo 256MB, not 1GB

Answer (score 68):

For `jsonb` fields, if you look at the [jsonb.c](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/REL_12_STABLE/src/backend/utils/adt/jsonb.c) in the source code, you'll see this function:

```c
checkStringLen(size_t len)
{
    if (len > JENTRY_OFFLENMASK)
        ereport(ERROR,
                (errcode(ERRCODE_PROGRAM_LIMIT_EXCEEDED),
                 errmsg("string too long to represent as jsonb string"),
                 errdetail("Due to an implementation restriction, jsonb strings cannot exceed %d bytes.",
                           JENTRY_OFFLENMASK)));

    return len;
}
```

Error code says that jsonb strings cannot exceed `JENTRY_OFFLENMASK` bytes.

In [jsonb.h](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/REL_12_STABLE/src/include/utils/jsonb.h), that constant is defined as:

```
#define JENTRY_OFFLENMASK       0x0FFFFFFF
```

which is **255 MB**.

I checked this in the source code for PostgreSQL 9.4 up to 15.

Comment: Not sure about the accepted answer claiming 1GB , but I ran into this exact error yesterday. And my json was just a bit over 300Mb in size.

Comment: because jsonb != json