# Can I use postgres JSON column types with Strongloop Loopback?

Tags: postgresql, loopbackjs

I am starting a new loopback project with a postgresql backend. I know that I will need to embed JSON objects into records and plan to use the native JSON and JSONB column types available in postgres. I noticed in the online docs that there is no reference to these 2 column types (here: http://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/PostgreSQL+connector).

Is it possible to create to use the column types? if so, how would I do that?

thanks,
Mark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm curious and haven't tried this.  Have you tried using an `Object` type with the `json` postgres data type?

```
"properties": {
  "dataProp": {
    "type": "Object",
    "required": false,
    "precision": null,
    "scale": null,
    "postgresql": {
      "columnName": "dataProp",
      "dataType": "json"
    }
  }
}
```

It seems to be supported here:
https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-connector-postgresql/blob/79d4fa03bb0922301a22e5d2a85444eadd621ab0/lib/postgresql.js#L480

Comment: I haven't tried it yet, but will. Seems that it might handle the JSON type but not the JSONB type.

Comment: it works both, thank you Bryan! One thing JSON/JSONB doesn't have length attribute it behaves as text on a PostgreSQL level, here is a discussion about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12632871/size-limit-of-json-data-type-in-postgresql

Comment: Great! I'll update the answer to remove the length attribute so others aren't confused.

Comment: I still cannot find JSONB in https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-connector-postgresql/blob/master/lib/postgresql.js, I am not sure if this is supported in the moment, especially GIN indexes. There is nothing referring in source code to JSONB or GIN, so this advanced stuff is not yet supported as per my understanding