# What happens if JSONField has reached maximum storage limit?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

This might be a simple question for an experienced (Django) developer.

My project's database is PostgreSQL.

I intend to use a single protected model instance as a centralised storage for certain data. That instance will have a JSONField which will, in turn, store a dynamic collection of key-value pairs (both are strings). By "dynamic" I mean that new key-value pairs will be added to the collection from time to time, and hence the collection will constantly grow in size.

As far as I have read (e.g. [Size limit of JSON data type in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12632871/size-limit-of-json-data-type-in-postgresql)), the size limit of JSONField is approximately 1GB. That is quite a lot, but still not infinite.

My question is: what exactly will happen if I manage to exhaust the storage capacity of JSONField? And are there any recommendations on how to forecast this kind of situation before it happens (e.g. monitor the instance's storage size)?

Comment: Long before you reach that limit you'll have to deal with how long it takes to update 500MB of json in each of presumably a lot of rows. If you seriously want to store single documents of that size I'm not sure you want a database at all.

Comment: *new key-value pairs will be added to the collection from time to time*: in what frequency? If this is frequent enough, the table will contain a lot of dead tuples, which can slow down quering & VACUUMing. And needless to say that you cannot atomically update/insert a new pair: the whole JSON data will be overwritten every time. I strongly recommend using some relational design instead (even [EAV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity–attribute–value_model) can perform better in your use case).

Comment: Thanks for all your comments! Since the described storage solution now seems problematic in the long run, I've decided to try a project-wide key-value store, something like pickledb (https://github.com/patx/pickledb), instead.

Comment: * (pickledb is now using the "simplejson" module, contrary to the name.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you don't plan to manipulate the JSON value in the database, you should use data type `json` rather than `jsonb`.

If you exceed that limit, you will get an error message. But since the whole value temporarily has to be kept in RAM on the client side and the database side, I'd expect that you run into problems before that – you'll probably get an out of memory message from the database, or the performance might be really bad.

If you have more than 1GB of state to store in the database, it might be a good idea to split that into several parts and update only those parts that really got changed, like you normally do in a relational database.

Answer (score 1):

Here is almost you wanted.

- Postgresql Limit details
  https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/FAQ#What_is_the_maximum_size_for_a_row.2C_a_table.2C_and_a_database.3F
- What if limit exceed

  https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/TOAST

Comment: Thanks! But does the second piece of info mean that the TOAST mechanism will prevent "hitting the wall" upon reaching the JSONField maximum size limit?

Comment: Never tested it. But it will as per the information.