# Json field truncated in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, json, sqlalchemy

I am getting my data from my postgres database but it is truncated. For VARCHAR, I know it's possible to set the max size but is it possible to do it too with JSON, or is there an other way?

Here is my request:

```py
robot_id_cast = cast(RobotData.data.op("->>")("id"), String)
robot_camera_cast = cast(RobotData.data.op("->>")(self.camera_name), JSON)

# Get the last upload time for this robot and this camera
subquery_last_upload = (
    select([func.max(RobotData.time).label("last_upload")])
            .where(robot_id_cast == self.robot_id)
            .where(robot_camera_cast != None)
        ).alias("subquery_last_upload")

main_query = (
    select(
    [subquery_last_upload.c.last_upload,RobotData.data.op("->")(self.camera_name).label(self.camera_name),])
            .where(RobotData.time == subquery_last_upload.c.last_upload)
            .where(robot_id_cast == self.robot_id)
            .where(robot_camera_cast != None)
        )
```

The problem is with this select part `RobotData.data.op("->")(self.camera_name).label(self.camera_name)`

Here is my table

```py
class RobotData(PGBase):
    __tablename__ = "wr_table"

    time = Column(DateTime, nullable=False, primary_key=True)
    data = Column(JSON, nullable=False)
```

Edit: My JSON is 429 characters

Answer (score 0):

The limit of JSON datatype is 1GB in PostgreSQL.

Refs:

- https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/286357
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/12633183

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to mention mine is 429 characters, far from it